# Are there any Int24 implementations in C#?

Tags: c#, types

I have a project that I am working on where I require a data type that doesn't exist in the .NET BCL - an Unsigned Int24. For calculations that I am doing, the 4th byte in an int32, even when set to all zeroes, screws up my results.

EDIT:
I'm doing bitwise circular shifts on a 24bit integer space that is limited to only 24bits. If the rotation is performed at 24bit level on a 32bit number the result is wildly incorrect.

Does anyone know of any third party implementations of this data type that are available?

Thanks!

Comment: How can a fourth byte screw things up? Are you marshalling to unmanaged code? If not, maybe explain a bit further why `[U]Int32` will not work.

Comment: Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4378218/62576) can offer some ideas on how to implement it yourself, although I can't see any reason a 4th byte in an int32 would cause problems unless you're doing something wrong. It's hard to say, though, because you posted zero code that demonstrates how it "screws things up".

Comment: Seeming as .NET is little-endian on x86 a fourth MSB shouldn't cause any problems unless the library's defined 24-bit handling code makes assumptions about the memory layout.

Comment: The CPU does not have a 24-bit rotate instruction so there's no benefit in trying to simulate a 24-bit integer in C#.

Comment: Your assumption would be incorrect since I have implemented my own rotate implementation. Trying to simulate a 24bit int is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Implementing Int24 isn't hard (honest!). But we need to know more about why you need to implement it. @nneonneo wonders if you're trying to interface with a native library that uses 24-bit integers. If that's the case then you can be done by doing something like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct UInt24 {
    private Byte _b0;
    private Byte _b1;
    private Byte _b2;

    public UInt24(UInt32 value) {
        _b0 = (byte)( (value      ) & 0xFF );
        _b1 = (byte)( (value >>  8) & 0xFF ); 
        _b2 = (byte)( (value >> 16) & 0xFF );
    }

    public unsafe Byte* Byte0 { get { return &_b0; } }

    public UInt32 Value { get { return _b0 | ( _b1 << 8 ) | ( _b2 << 16 ); } }
}

// Usage:

[DllImport("foo.dll")]
public static unsafe void SomeImportedFunction(byte* uint24Value);

UInt24 uint24 = new UInt24( 123 );
SomeImportedFunction( uint24.Byte0 );
```

Modifying the class for big-endian or signed Int24 is an exercise left up to the reader.

Comment: I'm doing circular shifts (the rotate command in ASM) on 24bit color values for an experiment that I am working on - the experiment requires that I work in no more than 24bit space. If I perform a rotation meant for 24bits on a 32bit number with zeroes, the resulting number is incorrect.

Comment: That's something you could implement yourself by performing bitshifts on individual bytes and manipulating the results (and overflows) such that the effect is maintained. That said, can't you use 32-bit ARGB values in your environment?

Comment: Unfortunately not with the hardware that this will output to - a 24bit width pipeline is all that is available. Your answer helps out a lot though - thanks!

Comment: I get Compiler Error CS0212 saying that I need a fixed statement initializer. Not finding much info on what a "fixed statement initializer is"

Comment: @Goku You need to either compile with the `/unsafe` switch or use a `fixed( byte* b = yourUint24Value.Byte0 )` statement.

Comment: The offending line is "public unsafe Byte* Byte0 { get { return &_b0; } }"

Comment: @Goku Ah - yes. That requires the `/unsafe` compiler switch.