# C# is there any way to convert byte[]/int32 to int24?

Tags: c#

I have a file. I've readed 3 bytes from offset 05. So how can I convert that byte[] to int24? Or if I convert that array to int32 and then convert that int32 to int24, it will work? And how to convert?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110567/converting-byte-array-to-int24/18195017#18195017

Answer (score 2):

Int24 isn't directly supported, however there is a similar question that describes how to achieve what you need:

```
public struct UInt24 {
   private Byte _b0;
   private Byte _b1;
   private Byte _b2;

   public UInt24(UInt32 value) {
       _b0 = (byte)(value & 0xFF);
       _b1 = (byte)(value >> 8); 
       _b2 = (byte)(value >> 16);
   }

   public unsafe Byte* Byte0 { get { return &_b0; } }
   public UInt32 Value { get { return _b0 | ( _b1 << 8 ) | ( _b2 << 16 ); } }
```

}

```
UInt24 uint24 = new UInt24( 123 );
```

[Are there any Int24 implementations in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549197/are-there-any-int24-implementations-in-c)

Comment: i need signed int24.i just know int24 is 3 bytes :D

Comment: @user1926930 but you won't find a type Int24 :D