# Converting Byte Array To Int24

Tags: c#, byte

I am reading a file with BinaryReader.

There are data I want to pull at the address 0x37E but it is int24. So even I read 3 bytes, I can't convert it to int24.

Do you have any suggestion?

I'm using C# and am working on STFS package stuff.

Comment: What language is this? Show us your current code (well, a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) of it). And [edit] the question with this information rather than using the comments.

Comment: I'd suggest that you tell us about which language you talk about...

Comment: Aahhh sorry im a little bit sleepy :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to transform a byte array to an int24, you need to know the endianness of the data. This means: the information if `11 22 33` is supposed to mean `0x112233` or `0x332211`.

Depending on this endianness, you can convert the data such as

```
int24 result_bigendian = array[0] * 65536 + array[1] * 256 + array[2] // (1)
```

or

```
int24 result_littleendian = array[2] * 65536 + array[1] * 256 + array[0] // (2)
```

(resp.

```
int24 result_littleendian = array[0] + array[1] * 256 + array[2] * 65536 // (3)
```

if you prefer that; note the difference to (1))

I don't know about C#; there may be an easier way to reach the goal.

Comment: it is little endian so i use below one ?

Comment: exactly. Maybe (3) `array[0] + array[1] * 256 + array[2] * 65536` looks better...

Comment: As (2) and (3) are semantically identical, you are free to choose amongst them.

Answer (score 5):

For **signed int24, little endian** use:

```
int num = array[0] | array[1] << 8 | (sbyte)array[2] << 16;
```

For **signed int24, big endian** use:

```
int num = (sbyte)array[0] << 16 | array[1] << 8 | array[2];
```

For **unsigned int24, little endian** use:

```
int num = array[0] | array[1] << 8 | array[2] << 16;
```

For **unsigned int24, big endian** use:

```
int num = array[0] << 16 | array[1] << 8 | array[2];
```

---

Note that for any **signed int, little endian** of **n** bytes, just **list** all the bytes, **connect** them using a '|', **shift** them one by one, and **add (sbyte)** to the last byte to make it signed:

```
var num = array[0] | array[1] << 8 | array[2] << 16 | ... | (sbyte)array[n] << 8*n;
```

For **big endian**, just reverse the shift order:

```
var num = array[n] | array[n-1] << 8 | array[n-2] << 16 | ... | (sbyte)array[0] << 8*n;
```

Or, of course, alternatively:

```
var num = (sbyte)array[0] << 8*n | array[1] << 8*(n-1) | ... | array[0];
```

You have to make sure that the **(sbyte)** is with the **highest order byte** (the last byte if little endian, the first byte if big endian) to get C# create the sign for the int.

Of course, for **unsigned int**, just remove the **(sbyte)**.

---

Last thing.. the **array** can be **byte[]** or **int[]**. So you can do this:

```
var num = stream.ReadByte() | stream.ReadByte() << 8 | (sbyte)stream.ReadByte() << 16;
```

Where **stream** is a **System.IO.Stream**.

Answer (score 2):

I have written an extension method for this problem some time ago.

```
public enum Endian : int {
    Little,
    Big
}

public static int ToInt32(this byte[] buffer, Endian endian = Endian.Little) {
    if (buffer.Length < 1 || buffer.Length > 4)
        throw new ArgumentException(" ... ");

    if (endian == Endian.Big)
        buffer.Reverse();

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = buffer.Length - 1; i > -1; --i)
        sum += (buffer[i] << (i << 3));

    if ((buffer[buffer.Length - 1] & 0x80) == 0x80)
        sum |= (0xFFFFFF << (buffer.Length << 3));

    return sum;
}

public static unsafe void Reverse(this byte[] buffer) {
    fixed (byte* b = buffer) {
        byte* s, e;
        s = b;
        e = b + buffer.Length - 1;

        byte t;                
        while (s < e) {
            t = *s;
            *s = *e;
            *e = t;
            ++s;
            --e;
        }
    }
}
```

The ***Endian enum*** and the ***Reverse method*** are used by the ToInt32 method for Endian purposes.

The ToInt32 method has some nice benefits:

**1.** It's an extension method so you can call it with your byte[] object.

```
byte[] x = { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x7F };
int value = x.ToInt32();
```

**2.** It's able to convert the byte array to both byte orders.

```
byte[] x = { 0x12, 0x34, 0x56 };
int valueLittle = x.ToInt32(Endian.Little); // Return 5,649,426
int valueBig    = x.ToInt32(Endian.Big);    // Return 1,193,046
```

**3.** It takes care of the sign bit.

```
byte[] x = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x80 };
x.ToInt32();           // Return -8,388,608
x.ToInt32(Endian.Big); // Return 128
```

I've tried to make the methods so fast as I can. Did some benchmarks and speed was good for me.
Hope this solution helps and makes the life easier. ;)

Comment: Shouldnt it be int24 instead of int32?

Comment: Well, it does if you pass an byte[3].

    byte[] x = { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff };
    x.ToInt32(); // Returns -1 like expected

Comment: i dont have time for calculate, sorry.can you tell me if it can convert to int24 or not?

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement [@glglgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296974/glglgl) answer, in C# you can try the following:

```
public int ReadInt24(byte[] array, int pos)
{
    if(array == null || array.Length < 3)
       return -1; //some invalid value
    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        return ((array[2]) + (array[1] * 256) + (array[0] * 65536));
    else
        return ((array[0]) + (array[1] * 256) + (array[2] * 65536));
}
```

The property [BitConverter.IsLittleEndian](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian.aspx) will tell about the current Endianness

> Indicates the byte order ("endianness") in which data is stored in
>   this computer architecture.

Comment: i know what endianness is :D

Comment: @TCBurakAvcı, great that you know, but this answer might help future visitors like me :)

Comment: Ahh Thanks anyway.I'm trying to improve myself more :D

Answer (score 0):

For signed int24 use:

```
int num = array[0] | array[1] << 8 | (sbyte)array[2] << 16;
```