# Convert byte array (hex) to signed Int

Tags: powershell, type-conversion, hex, powershell-4.0

I am trying to convert a (variable length) Hex String to Signed Integer (I need either positive or negative values).

[Int16] [int 32] and [int64] **seem** to work fine with 2,4+ byte length Hex Strings but I'm stuck with 3 byte strings [int24] (*no such command in powershell*).

Here's what I have now (snippet):

```
$start = $mftdatarnbh.Substring($DataRunStringsOffset+$LengthBytes*2+2,$StartBytes*2) -split "(..)"
[array]::reverse($start)
$start = -join $start

if($StartBytes*8 -le 16){$startd =[int16]"0x$($start)"}
elseif($StartBytes*8 -in (17..48)){$startd =[int32]"0x$($start)"}
else{$startd =[int64]"0x$($start)"}
```

With the above code, a $start value of "D35A71" gives '13851249' instead of '-2925967'. I tried to figure out a way to implement two's complement but got lost. Any easy way to do this right?

Thank you in advance

**Edit**: Basically, I think I need to implement something like this:
`int num = (sbyte)array[0] << 16 | array[1] << 8 | array[2];`
as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110567/converting-byte-array-to-int24).

Just tried this:

`$start = "D35A71"

[sbyte]"0x$($start.Substring(0,2))" -shl 16 -bor "0x$($start.Substring(2,2))" -shl 8 -bor "0x$($start.Substring(4,2))"`

but doesn't seem to get the correct result :-/

Comment: Would you like to use C#?

Comment: I don't know C#, but tried to find a code to do the same & convert it. That's where I got lost (in the translation) ..

Comment: What is this for?  0xD35A71 is 13851249 in decimal.

Comment: $MFT FILE record dataruns
Look at the mostsignificant bit:

1101 0011 0101 1010 0111 0001‬

This is a negative number

Comment: A DWORD is represented by 32-bits, not 24-bits.  Thus, the most-significant bit is actually a zero (0): `0000 0000 1101 0011 0101 1010 0111 0001`

Comment: Just type: `[convert]::ToString("0xD35A71",2) .length` 

The result is 24 bits : `110100110101101001110001` (3 bytes). A DWORD is 32 bits..24 bits is an SWORD [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-bit_computing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To **parse your hex.-number string as a *negative* number** you can **use `[bigint]`** ([`System.Numerics.BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Numerics.BigInteger)):

```
# Since the most significant hex digit has a 1 as its most significant bit
# (is >= 0x8), it is parsed as a NEGATIVE number.
# To force unconditional interpretation as a positive number, prepend '0'
# to the input hex string.
PS> [bigint]::Parse('D35A71', 'AllowHexSpecifier')
-2925967
```

You can cast the resulting `[bigint]` instance back to an `[int]` (`System.Int32`).

Note:

- **The result is a *negative* number, because the *most significant hex digit* of the hex input string is `>= 0x8`** (binary `1000`), i.e. has its *high bit set* (meaning: the most significant of the 4 bits that make up a given hex digit is `1`).

  - To force `[bigint]` to unconditionally interpret a hex. input string as a *positive* number, *prepend `0`*.
- **The internal [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation of a resulting *negative* number is performed at *byte* boundaries**, so that a given hex number with an *odd* number of digits (i.e. if the first hex digit is a "half byte") has the missing half byte filled with `1` bits.
- Therefore, **a hex-number string whose most significant digit is `>= 0x8`  (parses as a *negative* number) results in the *same* number as prepending *one or more* `F`s (`0xF` == `1111`) to it**; e.g., the following calls *all* result in `-2048`:
  `[bigint]::Parse('800', 'AllowHexSpecifier')`,
  `[bigint]::Parse('F800', 'AllowHexSpecifier')`,
  `[bigint]::Parse('FF800', 'AllowHexSpecifier'`), ...

See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger#working-with-byte-arrays-and-hexadecimal-strings) for details about the parsing logic.

---

**Examples:**

```
# First digit (7) is < 8 (high bit NOT set) -> positive number
[bigint]::Parse('7FF', 'AllowHexSpecifier') # -> 2047

# First digit (8) is >= 8 (high bit IS SET) -> negative number
[bigint]::Parse('800', 'AllowHexSpecifier') # -> -2048

# Prepending additional 'F's to a number that parses as 
# a negative number yields the *same* result
[bigint]::Parse('F800', 'AllowHexSpecifier') # -> -2048
[bigint]::Parse('FF800', 'AllowHexSpecifier') # -> -2048
# ...

# Starting the hex-number string with '0' 
# *unconditionally* makes the result a *positive* number
[bigint]::Parse('0800', 'AllowHexSpecifier') # -> 2048
```

Comment: It works exactly as I wanted it. Replaced the "IF" part of my code snippet (above) with   
`$startd = [bigint]::Parse($start, 'AllowHexSpecifier')`  
and tested it with a full $MFT parse. The results for each (negative) data run are now correct. Thank you again!